# add prefix to the recursively expanded variable in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have :

```
COMP_FILE+=docker-compose.con-etl.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.abc.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.cde.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.efg.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.hij.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.klm.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.nmo.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.pqr.yml
```

and i need to add -f before each and every docker-compose,for e.g result should be

```
-f docker-compose.con-etl.yml -f ${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.abc.yml -f ${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.cde.yml -f ${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.efg.yml -f ${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.hij.yml -f ${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.klm.yml -f ${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.nmo.yml -f ${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.pqr.yml
```

i am using the below command but unable to get the required result  and getting

```
COMPOSE_FILE_ARGS=$(echo ${COMPOSE_FILE[@]/#/-f })

-f docker-compose.con-etl.yml${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.abc.yml${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.cde.yml${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.efg.yml${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.hij.yml${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.klm.yml${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.nmo.yml${PWD}/datahub/docker-compose.pqr.yml
```

can anyone help me

Comment: Where's the recursive part? What do you really want to do? What is the input? This is just one variable. Why don't you just `COMP_FILE='-f docker-compose.yml -f another_docker'` ?

Comment: COMP_FILE is recursive expanded variable,and is there any way if i can add -f in COMP_FILE

Comment: It is not expanded recursively, there is no recursion here. It is appended. This is just a string. And you append to the end of the string new path's to docker. Just append with `-f`. And remember to append spaces to the variable.

Comment: yes,you can say that this is appended but in "MAKE" it is called recursively expanded

Comment: You need to fix your tags. Linux `"shell"` does not support arrays of any kind (bash and other advanced shells do). What `"shell"` are you actually running?

Comment: i need to do it in bash

Comment: 1. This is not make nor makefile, but shell script. 2. This is not recursive expansion in make. Recursive expansion happens when you have one variable with a value, then a second variable with a string `$(first_var_name)`. Then the expansion on the second variable causes it to be double expanded. The expansion happens until all `$( ... )` are resolved. 3. You are appending string to a variable. Why don't you append it with `-f` and spaces? `COMP_FILE+=docker-compose.con-etl.yml ; COMP_FILE+=' -f '; COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.abc.yml ; ... etc.` 4. Still `+=` is called "appending" in make

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems. You are not creating an array, you are creating a long string as the first element. To create the array with a command as each element, you need to enclose the values assigned to the array in `(...)` parenthesis, e.g.

```
COMP_FILE+=(docker-compose.con-etl.yml)
COMP_FILE+=(${PWD}/docker-compose.abc.yml)
COMP_FILE+=(${PWD}/docker-compose.cde.yml)
COMP_FILE+=(${PWD}/docker-compose.efg.yml)
COMP_FILE+=(${PWD}/docker-compose.hij.yml)
COMP_FILE+=(${PWD}/docker-compose.klm.yml)
COMP_FILE+=(${PWD}/docker-compose.nmo.yml)
COMP_FILE+=(${PWD}/docker-compose.pqr.yml)
```

To iterate over the array adding `"-f "` as a prefix to each command, you can use a C-style for loop to loop over each index assigning `"-f "` as a prefix:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#COMP_FILE[@]}; i++)); do
    COMP_FILE[i]="-f ${COMP_FILE[i]}"
done
```

To confirm the prefixes have been added, just output the resulting array,

```
for i in "${COMP_FILE[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash yamlfile.sh
-f docker-compose.con-etl.yml
-f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.abc.yml
-f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.cde.yml
-f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.efg.yml
-f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.hij.yml
-f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.klm.yml
-f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.nmo.yml
-f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.pqr.yml
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

**Edit Per-Request of All In One Line**

You have the information stored in the array as you needed. You put that in any format you like, for instance "all in one line"

```
echo "${COMP_FILE[@]}"
-f docker-compose.con-etl.yml -f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.abc.yml -f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.cde.yml -f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.efg.yml -f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.hij.yml -f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.klm.yml -f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.nmo.yml -f /tmp/tmp-david/docker-compose.pqr.yml
```

You can simply use the expansion of all elements in the array in any command needed while ensuring each component is `"-f ......"`.

Let me know if that doesn't do it for you.

Comment: :many thanks for the help but solution is coming line by line ,however i need all in one line like -f docker-compose.con-etl.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.abc.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.cde.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.efg.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.hij.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.klm.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.nmo.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.pqr.yml

Comment: @AnkurSharma - it was already stored in that manner in the array. It was output with line breaks to keep the result from scrolling off the page. You simply use `"${COMP_FILE[@]}"` for the entire line as you have requested.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cat` and `sed`:

```
$ cat <<'end' | sed 's/=/=" -f /;s/$/"/' > script.sh
COMP_FILE=docker-compose.con-etl.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.abc.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.cde.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.efg.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.hij.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.klm.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.nmo.yml
COMP_FILE+=${PWD}/docker-compose.pqr.yml
end
```

then source the generated script.sh to get:

```
$ . script.sh
$ echo $COMP_FILE
-f docker-compose.con-etl.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.abc.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.cde.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.efg.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.hij.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.klm.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.nmo.yml -f /home/sergioro/docker-compose.pqr.yml
```